# MS Project Server Web App 2013 Allow Task for Weekends

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-project-server-2013

How do i enable tasks to be scheduled during the weekends.  Right now any task that falls on Saturday or Sunday get bumped to Monday of next week.
In our scenario some people work weekends.
We are using Project Server 2013 with Sharepoint 2013.
If we set dates on any weekend it automatically changes the dates.  I want to keep the auto schedule on but allow work on weekends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this depending on your scenario.  If you have a specific group of users who always works weekends, you can create an enterprise calendar for that and set the working times to add/allow weekend scheduling and assign it to the resources.  If it is specific work schedule, and not resources, do the same by creating an enterprise calendar and set the working times, and you can assign it task by task in the project schedule.

- Open Schedule in Project Pro
- Insert "Task Calendar" column
- Assign to the specific task(s)

To create an enterprise calendar
- Server Settings - Enterprise Data - Enterprise Calendar
- Create new or edit existing
- Calendar will be edited through project pro.

Hope this helps!